# Issue with UIPageViewControllerDataSource using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

The `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` delegate has two required methods: `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController`.

I have encountered an issue. Here's the code I am using.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerBeforeViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    // ...
    print("You swiped BACK")
    return: nil
}
```

and

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {  
        ...
        println("You swiped FORWARD")

        return nil
}
```

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem:

- I swipe to the right
- the console's output is

> You swiped BACK
>   You swiped FORWARD

This happens when I swipe to the left too. Why is the console printing both of them and not just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because both of these functions are called upon transition as all 3 (previous, current, and next) view controllers are instantiated. Thus when you transition to view controller 2, view controllers 1 and 3 are instantiated.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
 viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

These functions do not indicate which direction the user swipes, but rather the next and previous view controller

To get the swipe, you implement `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` and its `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` or `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:` functions or add an observer to `UIPageViewController`'s gesture recognizer